# Flask-classy routes from another file

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create some routes for Flask using Flask-Classy. I did it without any problems when the class-based views are in the same file in the routes.py.
Is there any ways to move the class-based views to another file?

```
class RegionView(FlaskView):
    def index(self):
        return render_template('regions.html', title="Regions")

    def hello(self):
        return "in hello"


RegionView.register(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

as shown above, I want the code above to be in another file instead of being in the routes.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Make new file called `region_view.py`. Add the FlaskView Class there:

```
class RegionView(FlaskView):
    def index(self):
        return render_template('regions.html', title="Regions")

    def hello(self):
        return "in hello"
```

In your main/init file:

```
from region_view import RegionView

RegionView.register(app, route_base='/route')
```